# iframe 内でのリンク移動

Tags: html, html5

```
<p><a href="https://www.google.co.jp/">Google.co.jp</a></p>
```

上のようなHTMLファイル `frame.html` が有ったとして、これを下記のHTMLで読み込みました。

```
<html>
  <iframe src="frame.html"></frame>
</html>
```

するとリンクは表示されるのですが、クリックするとブランクの真っ白な状態になってしまいます。
どうすれば回避可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

ページが真っ白に表示される理由は、google.co.jpをフレーム内に表示しようとしているせいです。
google.co.jpのページにはX-Frame-OptionsヘッダにSAMEORIGINが設定されており、別ドメインからはフレーム内で表示することはできません。
そのために、真っ白に表示され、回避することは難しいでしょう。
X-Frame-Optionsヘッダに対応していないブラウザでは表示することはできると思いますが、最近のブラウザはほとんど対応済みだと思います。

X-Frame-OptionsヘッダはChromeのDeveloper toolsの以下の場所から確認することができます。

[image: ChromeのDeveloper tools]

X-Frame-Optionsヘッダについては以下のURLを参考にしてください。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: `target`属性で`_top`を指定してあげるといいような気がします。[MDNのA要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) [日本語訳](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)